# Jquery .appendTo on multiple divs with same class

Tags: html, jquery

I am trying to relocate divs using jquery .appendTo but it is repeating divs in each selector. It is taking heading from each div and putting individually in the parent div. Please look at brief explanation below.

### Current Look

```
            <div class="parentdiv">
                <div class="foo">Heading 1</div>
                <div class="moo">Text</div>
            </div>

            <div class="parentdiv">
                <div class="foo">Heading 2</div>
                <div class="moo">Text</div>
            </div>

            <div class="parentdiv">
                <div class="foo">Heading 3</div>
                <div class="moo">Text</div>
            </div>
```

#### I want to move the `.foo` inside .moo so it looks same as below.

```
            <div class="parentdiv">

                <div class="moo">
                    <div class="foo">Heading 1</div>
                    Text
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="parentdiv">

                <div class="moo">
                    <div class="foo">Heading 2</div>
                    Text
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="parentdiv">

                <div class="moo">
                    <div class="foo">Heading 3</div>
                    Text
                </div>
            </div>
```

## But it is repeating and outputting as below

```
            <div class="parentdiv">

                <div class="moo">
                    Text
                    <div class="foo">Heading 1</div>
                    <div class="foo">Heading 2</div>
                    <div class="foo">Heading 3</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="parentdiv">

                <div class="moo">
                    Text
                    <div class="foo">Heading 1</div>
                    <div class="foo">Heading 2</div>
                    <div class="foo">Heading 3</div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="parentdiv">

                <div class="moo">
                    Text
                    <div class="foo">Heading 1</div>
                    <div class="foo">Heading 2</div>
                    <div class="foo">Heading 3</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Jquery: `$(".parentdiv .foo").appendTo(".parentdiv .moo");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.prepend()`](https://api.jquery.com/prepend/) with a callback function to do this:

```js
$('.moo').prepend(function() {
  return $(this).prev()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parentdiv">
  <div class="foo">Heading 1</div>
  <div class="moo">Text</div>
</div>

<div class="parentdiv">
  <div class="foo">Heading 2</div>
  <div class="moo">Text</div>
</div>

<div class="parentdiv">
  <div class="foo">Heading 3</div>
  <div class="moo">Text</div>
</div>
```

This produces:

```
<div class="parentdiv">
  <div class="moo">
    <div class="foo">Heading 1</div>
    Text
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parentdiv">
  <div class="moo">
    <div class="foo">Heading 2</div>
    Text
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parentdiv">
  <div class="moo">
    <div class="foo">Heading 3</div>
    Text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's super clean, not my question but I appreciate this answer. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

It might be late, but here's what you can do.
you can use .each function for this,

```
$(".parent-div").each(function() {
  var headingDiv = $(this).find(".foo");
  var textDiv = $(this).find(".moo");
  headingDiv.appendTo(textDiv);
});
```